# WordPress Admin Ajax from TinyMCE Modal

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm attempting to access admin ajax and nonce variables for an Ajax call from a Tiny Modal window in the WordPress admin, however my calls to the ajax admin url and nonce are returning undefined.

**Localization script**

```
<?php function alm_admin_vars() { ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 /* <![CDATA[ */
var alm_admin_localize = <?php echo json_encode( array( 
    'ajax_admin_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'alm_admin_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'alm_repeater_nonce' )
)); ?>
/* ]]> */
</script><?php }
```

The variable `alm_admin_localize` has been created on the parent window, not the TinyMCE modal so I believe that is the issue. It is returning 'undefined' from the TinyMCE modal.

**My Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: alm_admin_localize.ajax_admin_url,
        data: {
            action: 'alm_get_tax_terms',
            taxonomy: tax,
            nonce: alm_admin_localize.alm_admin_nonce,
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(data) {           
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
```

This Ajax call needs to be reused from the TinyMCE modal as well as a standard WordPress Plugin setting screen.

Is there a way to access the 'alm_admin_localize` variable from the TinyMCE Modal window?

I've looked at using `window.opener` but that does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Wow, sometimes I really try to over complicate things... The answer was to add window.parent before the call to the alm_admin_localize variable. So the final Ajax call looks like this, window.parent.alm_admin_localize.ajax_admin_url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but it would clarify things a bit to have your client and server communicate via JSON rather than HTML:

#### Server-Side

```
<?php

function alm_admin_vars() {
    return array(
        'alm_admin_localize' => array(
            'ajax_admin_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'alm_admin_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'alm_repeater_nonce' )
        )
    );
}

// Respond with JSON
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(alm_admin_vars());
```

#### Client-Side

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    ...
    success: function(data) {           
        console.log('My alm_admin_localize data:', data.alm_admin_localize);
        // Ready to update the DOM related to TinyMCE modal
    }
});
```

Assuming you can make the same AJAX call from the TinyMCE modal, `alm_admin_localize` should now be available in the callback there to do with as you please.